# how to unlock Xperia from emergency call display

Tags: lock-screens

After booting, my Xperia M2 mobile is locked and displayed Emergency call

How should I do to get out from this screen and go to the home screen ?

Regards,

Patrice.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my problem
I activated screen lock with the SIM code.
So I had to enter the SIM code twice.